Only the Vue frontend is displayed until the OpenVidu components are used so there is no request to the backend
I encountered a problem while deploying the application. I have developed a frontend using Vue.js for a vidcon app. I used the OpenVidu platform for it. I followed their documentation. To start, I need to deploy a Docker container using the command:
docker run -p 4443:4443 --rm -e OPENVIDU_SECRET=MY_SECRET openvidu/openvidu-dev:2.29.0 

Afterwards, I got their Java backend from GitHub(https://github.com/OpenVidu/openvidu-tutorials/tree/master/openvidu-basic-java). I will also provide the code below.
package io.openvidu.basic.java;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }


package io.openvidu.basic.java;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.openvidu.java.client.Connection;
import io.openvidu.java.client.ConnectionProperties;
import io.openvidu.java.client.OpenVidu;
import io.openvidu.java.client.OpenViduHttpException;
import io.openvidu.java.client.OpenViduJavaClientException;
import io.openvidu.java.client.Session;
import io.openvidu.java.client.SessionProperties;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class Controller {

  @Value("${OPENVIDU_URL}")
  private String OPENVIDU_URL;

  @Value("${OPENVIDU_SECRET}")
  private String OPENVIDU_SECRET;

  private OpenVidu openvidu;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    this.openvidu = new OpenVidu(OPENVIDU_URL, OPENVIDU_SECRET);
  }

  /
   * @param params The Session properties
   * @return The Session ID
   */
  @PostMapping("/api/sessions")
  public ResponseEntity<String> initializeSession(@RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> params)
      throws OpenViduJavaClientException, OpenViduHttpException {
    SessionProperties properties = SessionProperties.fromJson(params).build();
    Session session = openvidu.createSession(properties);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(session.getSessionId(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  /
   * @param sessionId The Session in which to create the Connection
   * @param params    The Connection properties
   * @return The Token associated to the Connection
   */
  @PostMapping("/api/sessions/{sessionId}/connections")
  public ResponseEntity<String> createConnection(@PathVariable("sessionId") String sessionId,
      @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> params)
      throws OpenViduJavaClientException, OpenViduHttpException {
    Session session = openvidu.getActiveSession(sessionId);
    if (session == null) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    ConnectionProperties properties = ConnectionProperties.fromJson(params).build();
    Connection connection = session.createConnection(properties);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(connection.getToken(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

}

I run the Vue app on
server: { host: '0.0.0.0', }

I connect from my pc and everything works fine, but if I connect from another pc in the same local network, only the Vue frontend is displayed until the OpenVidu components are used so there is no request to the backend. Can you advise if I need to configure additional settings in the Docker container and in the Spring application? Any other solutions?
